# Angular dataSource connect doesn't launch

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I'm trying to display a list of item using angular mat table. this is my sample of code

*component.ts*

```
export class AllReportCardComponent
  extends UnsubscribeOnDestroyAdapter
  implements OnInit
{
  displayedColumns = [
    "select",
    "id",
    "reference",
    "classe",
    "utilisateur",
    "periode",
    "type",
    "actions",
  ];

  reportCardDatabase!: ReportCardService | null;
  reportCardDataSource!: ReportCardDataSource | null;
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<ReportCard>;
  selection = new SelectionModel<ReportCard>(true, []);
  id!: number;
  breadscrums = [
    {
      title: "Staff",
      items: ["Notes"],
      active: "Bulletins",
    },
  ];
  constructor(
    public httpClient: HttpClient,
    public dialog: MatDialog,
    public reportCardService: ReportCardService,
    private snackBar: MatSnackBar,
    private storage: UtilStorageService,
    private translate: TranslateService,
    private router: Router,
    private auth: AuthService
  ) {
    super();
  }
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator!: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort!: MatSort;
  @ViewChild("filter", { static: true }) filter!: ElementRef;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadData();
  }

  refresh() {
    this.loadData();
  }

  private refreshTable() {
    this.loadData();
    this.paginator._changePageSize(this.paginator.pageSize);
  }

  public loadData() {
    this.reportCardDatabase = new ReportCardService(
      this.httpClient,
      this.storage,
      this.translate,
      this.router,
      this.auth
    );
    this.reportCardDataSource = new ReportCardDataSource(
      this.reportCardDatabase,
      this.paginator,
      this.sort
    );
    this.subs.sink = fromEvent(this.filter.nativeElement, "keyup").subscribe(
      () => {
        if (!this.reportCardDataSource) {
          return;
        }
        this.reportCardDataSource.filter = this.filter.nativeElement.value;
      }
    );
  }
}

export class ReportCardDataSource extends DataSource<ReportCard> {
  filterChange = new BehaviorSubject("");

  get filter(): string {
    return this.filterChange.value;
  }

  set filter(filter: string) {
    this.filterChange.next(filter);
  }

  filteredData: ReportCard[] = [];
  renderedData: ReportCard[] = [];

  constructor(
    public reportCardDatabase: ReportCardService,
    public paginator: MatPaginator,
    public _sort: MatSort
  ) {
    super();
    // Reset to the first page when the user changes the filter.
    this.filterChange.subscribe(() => (this.paginator.pageIndex = 0));
  }

  /** Connect function called by the table to retrieve one stream containing the data to render. */
  connect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): Observable<ReportCard[]> {
    // Listen for any changes in the base data, sorting, filtering, or pagination
    this.reportCardDatabase.listReportCard();

    console.log("connect");

    const displayDataChanges = [
      this.reportCardDatabase.dataChange,
      this._sort.sortChange,
      this.filterChange,
      this.paginator.page,
    ];

    return merge(...displayDataChanges).pipe(
      map(() => {
        // Filter data
        this.filteredData = this.reportCardDatabase.data
          .slice()
          .filter((reportCard: ReportCard) => {
            const searchStr = (
              reportCard.utilisateur.nom +
              reportCard.classe.nom +
              reportCard.type +
              reportCard.periode
            ).toLowerCase();
            return searchStr.indexOf(this.filter.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
          });
        // Sort filtered data
        const sortedData = this.sortData(this.filteredData.slice());
        // Grab the page's slice of the filtered sorted data.
        const startIndex = this.paginator.pageIndex * this.paginator.pageSize;

        return (this.renderedData = sortedData.splice(
          startIndex,
          this.paginator.pageSize
        ));
      })
    );
  }

  disconnect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer) {
    this.reportCardDatabase.dataChange.complete();
    this.reportCardDatabase.isTblLoading.complete();
  }

  /** Returns a sorted copy of the database data. */
  sortData(data: ReportCard[]): ReportCard[] {
    if (!this._sort.active || this._sort.direction === "") {
      return data;
    }
    return data.sort((a, b) => {
      let propertyA: number | string = "";
      let propertyB: number | string = "";
      switch (this._sort.active) {
        case "id":
          [propertyA, propertyB] = [a.id, b.id];
          break;
        case "periode":
          [propertyA, propertyB] = [a.periode, b.periode];
          break;
        case "type":
          [propertyA, propertyB] = [a.type, b.type];
          break;
        case "utilisateur":
          [propertyA, propertyB] = [a.utilisateur.nom, b.utilisateur.nom];
          break;
        case "classe":
          [propertyA, propertyB] = [a.classe.nom, b.classe.nom];
          break;
      }
      const valueA = isNaN(+propertyA) ? propertyA : +propertyA;
      const valueB = isNaN(+propertyB) ? propertyB : +propertyB;
      return (
        (valueA < valueB ? -1 : 1) * (this._sort.direction === "asc" ? 1 : -1)
      );
    });
  }
}
```

and the *service.ts*

```
export class ReportCardService extends UnsubscribeOnDestroyAdapter {
  isTblLoading: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(true);
  dataChange: BehaviorSubject<ReportCard[]> = new BehaviorSubject<ReportCard[]>(
    []
  );
  // Temporarily stores data from dialogs
  dialogData: any;
  payload: any;
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private storage: UtilStorageService,
    private translate: TranslateService,
    private router: Router,
    private auth: AuthService
  ) {
    super();
    this.payload = auth.userInfo;
  }

  get data(): ReportCard[] {
    return this.dataChange.value;
  }

  get isLoading(): boolean {
    return this.isTblLoading.value;
  }

  getDialogData() {
    return this.dialogData;
  }

  generateBulletin(payload: any) {
    this.subs.sink = this.http
      .post<any>(
        `${path}/reporting/mark-book/generate`,
        payload,
        GLOBALS.HTTP_AUTH_OPTION
      )
      .subscribe({
        next: (res) => {
          this.isTblLoading.next(false);
        },
        error: (err) => {
          this.isTblLoading.next(false);
        },
      });
  }

  listReportCards(payload) {
    this.subs.sink = this.http
      .post<any>(
        `${path}/reporting/mark-book/list-filter`,
        payload,
        GLOBALS.HTTP_AUTH_OPTION
      )
      .subscribe({
        next: (res) => {
          this.isTblLoading.next(false);
          this.dataChange.next(res.data);
        },
        error: (err) => {
          this.isTblLoading.next(false);
        },
      });
  }

  listReportCard() {
    let payload = {
      referenceAnneeExercice: this.payload.exerciceAnnuel,
    };

    this.listReportCards(payload);
  }

  listReportCardU() {
    let payload = {
      referenceAnneeExercice: this.payload.exerciceAnnuel,
    };

    return this.http.post<any>(
      `${path}/reporting/mark-book/list-filter`,
      payload,
      GLOBALS.HTTP_AUTH_OPTION
    );
  }

  deleteNote(refNote: any) {
    this.subs.sink = this.http
      .delete<any>(
        `${path}/reporting/mark-book/archive/${refNote}`,
        GLOBALS.HTTP_AUTH_OPTION
      )
      .subscribe({
        next: (res) => {},
      });
  }
}
```

i'm not show the html part it is too long and not relevant cause the code in it is a simple common mat-table with the dataSource provided.

My problem is that the connect method in the custom dataSource is not even launched and my table don't display anything. Note that the console.log that i've added in connect method is not even showing in console.

Please i need some help.

Comment: Perhaps dataSource is not propertly initialised and populated subsequently?
Initialisation:
`@ViewChild('table') table: MatTable<FooList>;`
`dataSource: MatTableDataSource<FooList>;`
Push data on to it: `this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(FooList);`
Subsequently render rows in table: `this.table.renderRows();`

Comment: I've follow the angular material documentation for custom dataSource and there is no error in my code and this is where i'm initialised dataSource `this.reportCardDataSource = new ReportCardDataSource(
      this.reportCardDatabase,
      this.paginator,
      this.sort
    );`.